# Normal irreducible quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-space

> How can I show that an irreducible quadric $Q$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ is normal?

If $Q$ is non singular then the local ring associated to every point is a UFD and so a normal ring, but how can I do if the quadric has singular points?

Comment: Do you mean I have to work separatly on every case?

Comment: If I am not wrong, by the classification, an irreducible quadric in P^3 is non singular or it has a double point; in this case, I think we can reduce to the case that this point is the origin (in an affine chart). Then the local ring associated to this point is isomorphic to theh localization of the affine coordinate ring in the maximal ideal associated to the origin; this localization is a field, so it is integrally closed.

Comment: In this case use the affine chart U_w, which is the complement of the hyperplane w=0 if the ring associated to P^3 is k[x, y, z]. Then in the affine chart the singularity is (00,0)

Comment: The singularity is (0,0,0). The local ring associated is isomorphic to the affine coordinate ring localized in (x, y, z), but this is exactly the fraction field of k[x, y, z]. Since normality is a local property we conclude.

Comment: No, e.g. $x$ is not a unit in that localization. Make sure you understand the definition of localization at a prime before you proceed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I confused with localization in (0) I think; some suggestion about the problem? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is not too bad to work out by hand. I'm not sure that we even need to localize. Notice that the function field of your quadric cone is a degree-$2$ extension of $k(x,y)$, so anybody integral over $k[x,y]$ satisfies a degree-$2$ monic polynomial.

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand how you found the degree of the extension of the function field, and why you are using these ring and field; can you explain me? I consider a degree 2 homogeneous polynomial f \in k[x, y, z, w], which corresponds to a quadric in P^3; Is this quadric normal?

Comment: I know what your question is. It certainly suffices to check normality on an open affine containing the singularity, so look at the affine cone inside of $\mathbb A^3$. Now, can you write down the affine coordinate ring and function field of this variety?

Comment: Consider the quadric which has polynomial X^2+Y^2+Z^2 on an affine chart. Every elemenr of its coordinate ring can be written in the form            Xp(Y, Z)+q(Y, Z). Its fraction field, which is the function field of the quadric, is k(X,Y,Z); this can be seen taking fractions of elements of the coordinate ring and proving that 1/X, 1/Y and 1/Z can be written in that way. Now I can notice that this is also the fraction field of k[X, Y, Z], which is integrally closed since it is a UFD; then probably I have only to verify that the coordinate ring is normal on k[X,Y,Z], correct?

Comment: Well, your use of $k[X,Y,Z]$ is ambiguous. The polynomial ring (affine coordinate ring of $\mathbb A^3$ is surely a UFD, but if we think of $X,Y,Z$ with the relation $X^2+Y^2-Z^2$ (using $-$ rather than $+$ is more standard; it's the same over an algebraically closed field) gives non-unique factorization$Z^2=(X+Y)(X-Y)$, which in fact persists even to the local ring at the origin. So while this variety is normal, it is not locally factorial.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to identify the quotient ring with a subring of k[X, Y, Z]; if it is possible I think it will suffice to prove that every integral element of k[X, Y, Z] over the quotient subring is really in the quotient subring, and this is easy to prove using the relation X^2+Y^2-Z^2=0.

Comment: In general there is certainly no natural way to identify a quotient of a ring with a subring of that ring. Maybe in theory $k[X,Y,Z]$ has a subring isomorphic to the one you're interested in -- though I doubt it -- but if it does it can't come from mapping $X$ to $X$ and $Y$ to $Y$.

Comment: Thank you dor this remark. At this point I have no ideas: I can not find a homomorphism from the coordinate ring A to k[X, Y, Z], so I can not show it is an A-algebra and maybe it is really no; usually to find the normalization of a ring I try to exploit the relation given by the defining polynomial to find a monic relation, but in this case I can not find such relations.